# Fixed (Flexible) and Stretched (Expanded) elements in a Flex in Flutter

Tags: layout, flutter

In the Flutter layout system, I thought placing a `Flexible` and and `Expanded` in a `Column` would make the `Flexible` be the size of its children and the `Expanded` take up the whole remaining space. However, the `Expanded` does not fill up all of the remaining space and leaves some empty space that follows it.

Here is what I want to do:

```
+-----------------------------+
| Flexible, decides own size. |
+-----------------------------+
| Expanded, fills up the rest |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

However, this is what happens instead:

```
+-----------------------------+
| Flexible, decides own size. |
+-----------------------------+
| Expanded, takes up only     |
| some of the remaining space |
| looks like about 50% of     |
| the whole parent            |
|                             |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
| LOL here's unused space     |
| for no good reason          |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

I was doubting myself, then I saw the same thing reported as a bug for a row: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20575

I guess my question is, how can I have a fixed-size widget **(whose size is determined by its children)**, followed by a widget that takes up the rest of the parent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the answer is just to omit the `Flexible` in the first one and just put its contents there. Then, the `Expanded` fills up the rest of the space just fine.

So the solution is this:

```
+------------------------------+
| Just put your self-sized     |
| widget here without Flexible |
+------------------------------+
| Expanded, fills up the rest  |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```